# Find key for greatest value in hash of hashes in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash of hashes containing keys, values, and counts of the form ((k1, v1), c1).  I am trying to write a subroutine that returns the value of the key passed as a parameter with the greatest count.  For example, if I had:

```
%hash = (
    "a" => {
        "b" => 2,
        "c" => 1,
    },
    "d" => {
        "e" => 4,
    },
);
```

and made the call:

```
print &function("a");
```

it should print "b" because key "a" has the highest count of 2 with "b" as its value.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
sub function() {
    $key = $_[0];
    if(exists($hash{$key})) {
        while (my ($value, $count) = each %{$hash{$key}}) {
            #logic goes here
        }

    } else {
        return "$key does not exist";
    }
}
```

Comment: Parentheses do not a hash make. What you have is a list. Could you edit your post to include a [mcve]? It will help you formulate what the actual problem is...

Comment: @MattJacob I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [reduce](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#reduce) function from List::Util (which is part of core perl).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/reduce/;

my %hash = (
    "a" => {
        "b" => 2,
        "c" => 1,
    },
    "d" => {
        "e" => 4,
    },
);


my $key = 'a';
print  "For key: $key, max key is ", max_key($key, %hash), "\n";


sub max_key {
    my ($key, %hash) = @_;
    return "$key does not exist" unless exists $hash{$key};

    my $href = $hash{$key};
    return reduce { $href->{$a} > $href->{$b} ? $a : $b } keys %$href;
}
```

You should always include `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your programs to catch errors so you can find and fix them. This requires declaring of your variables with `my`, like `my $key = 'a';`, for example and `my %hash = ...`

This program prints:

```
For key: a, max key is b
```

Answer (score 5):

The sub doesn't need to know anything about the outer hash, so it makes far more sense to call the sub as follows:

```
print key_with_highest_val($hash{a});
```

The sub simply needs to iterate over all the elements of that hash, keeping track of the highest value seen, and the key at which it was seen.

```
sub key_with_highest_val {
   my ($h) = @_;
   my $hi_v;
   my $hi_k;
   for my $k (keys(%$h)) {
      my $v = $h->{$k};
      if (!defined($hi_v) || $v > $hi_v) {
         $hi_v = $v;
         $hi_k = $k;
      }
   }

   return $hi_k;
}
```

As Chris Charley points out, List::Util's `reduce` can simply this function. With the calling convention I recommended above, the `reduce` solution becomes the following:

```
use List::Util qw( reduce );

sub key_with_highest_val {
   my ($h) = @_;
   return reduce { $h->{$a} >= $h->{$b} ? $a : $b } keys(%$h);
}
```

Both versions return an arbitrary key among those that tied when there's a tie.

Answer (score 0):

This code makes the following assumptions:

1. The values of your nested hashes are always numeric.
2. You don't have duplicate values.

Anything else is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use List::Util qw(max);

my %hash = (
    a => {
        b => 2,
        c => 1,
    },
    d => {
        e => 4,
    },
);

dd(max_hash_value(\%hash, $_)) for 'a' .. 'd';

sub max_hash_value {
    my ($hash_ref, $search_key) = @_;
    return unless $hash_ref->{$search_key};

    my %lookup;

    while (my ($key, $value) = each(%{$hash_ref->{$search_key}})) {
        $lookup{$value} = $key;
    }

    return $lookup{max(keys(%lookup))};
}
```

Output:

```
"b"
()
()
"e"
```